# iOS Over the air installation not working - cannot connect to server

Tags: itunes, enterprise, ios

We are facing an issue while deployment of our enterprise iOS application. We are following the documentation from Apple link - https://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7

We have followed the below steps,

```
•   Created an ipa with our enterprise app provisioning profile. 
•   Created a manifest file that points to ipa and png files
•   Created an html with hyperlink to - itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://location.company.com/sites/mobile/Files/Mobile/deploy/manifest.plist
```

Hosted the html, ipa, manifest and png files in a folder in the server https://location.company.com.

The following mime type is in the web server

```
.plist -> application/xml 
.ipa -> application/octet-stream
```

We instructed our employees to access the download page, in the following way,

```
1.  Open https://location.company.com. It will as for userid and password. Need to login.
2.  Display a page which have install app link.
3.  Tap on the link to install the app.
```

When I trying to click on the link, I am getting an error:

```
Cannot connect to <>
```

I tried to download the plist file from my iOS browser. It is working fine.
The device log in the Xcode shows, the below log.

> Jun 23 15:17:15 TOM-iPhone itunesstored[106] : Could not load download
>   manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2
>   "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
>   I have checked with our IT team and confirmed that the certificates are valid.

But it is worked when I moved the plist, ipa and png files to dropbox and the link is

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/55yozabctc2npd6/manifest.plist
```

Only difference between these two what I feel is iTunes can access the link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/55yozabctc2npd6/manifest.plist directly. But iTunes cannot directly access the link - https://location.company.com/sites/mobile/Files/Mobile/deploy/manifest.plist, as it has an authentication page in between. That means if I open a fresh browser and try to open link - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/55yozabctc2npd6/manifest.plist, it download the file in my iPhone browser. But if I try the same with the link https://location.company.com/sites/mobile/Files/Mobile/deploy/manifest.plist it ask me for user name and password.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem, but I think it might have to do with the link to the ipa

Comment: The issue, I was facing was, the hyperlink to manifest.plist and ipa files are behind authentication. Can not access it directly. So our server team bypassed the URL for manifest.plist and .ipa file from the authentication. Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how we solved it.

The issue, I was facing was, the hyperlink to manifest.plist and ipa files are behind authentication. Can not access it directly. So our server team bypassed the URL for manifest.plist and .ipa file from the authentication.

Comment: What if I need authentication for those files? Any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36073537/4746648), any cookies required for authentication are lost during the install process, so the request to download the app (ipa file) will fail. You could try removing authentication for the link to the app, or maybe leaving the app file in Google Drive and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
In my case, the two MIME types were missing on my web server. After adding them, the Over-The-Air installation of an .ipa/manifest.plist went smoothlessly.

There was no authentication though for the .ipa and .plist files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may want to include instructions on how to add the two MIME types

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other responses you should make sure that your .ipa and .plist filenames do not contain any spaces. Even if you urlencode thoses spaces when linking to these files nothing will happen when you tap those links.